# Refresh Styles on Dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a console in the centre of a site, with links that dynamically change the html in the console  `<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('console/news.php', 'contentarea');">`

That all works fine but the new dynamically added html is not styled.

is there a way to refresh the .css either for the whole site or just for section of html that has been changed.

if i refresh the css for the whole site, i will put the css between `<styles>` instead of a link to save a trip to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new content has styles that are pre defined in your stylesheet, then it will be applied automatically. There's no 'refreshing' your css. Please clarify a bit more